# Ordinary Differential Equatiom

Tags: differential

$$\left(1-x^2\right) y''-4 x y'-\left(1+x^2\right) y=x $$

I am required to solve the above differential equation. Can't get around how to approach. Any help would be appreciated. $y' = \frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE community! We do not encourage plaintext math formulas on this site, it will be much better if you can format your math contents in MathJax. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/191404) for a quick guide.

Comment: I edited your equation. Check that it is exactly the one you need to solve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**

Try $$y(x)=\frac {z(x)}{1-x^2}$$ This will lead to a very simple differential equation in $z(x)$.

Comment: Thank you. But I can't see why this is simple. Just differentiating twice this function one get a kilometric expression, even after simplifying, and substituting in the original equation doesn't seem to render something very nice.

Comment: @Joanpemo. It is not *kilometric* and it simplifies to something very very simple.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will wait, perhaps the asker already got it. I tried and it became even longer than the original one.

Comment: Because of your comment, I did it again and I confirm. Cheers.

Comment: I couldn't think of this substitute. Works well.

Comment: In fact, knowing the result of the first substitution, the best substitution would have been $y(x)=\frac {z(x)+x}{1-x^2}$ (hard to find from scratch) leading to $z''(x)+z(x)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The method is the same as Claude Leibovici suggested, but maybe you should rather try the the following

$$z(x)=(1-x^2)y(x)$$
$$z'(x)=-2xy(x)+(1-x^2)y'(x)$$
$$z''(x)=-2y(x)-2xy'(x)-2xy'(x)+(1-x^2)y''(x)$$
$$z''(x)=(1-x^2)y''(x)-4xy'(x)-2y(x)$$

Adding 
$$y(x)(1-x^2)$$ 
on both sides results in

$$z''(x)+y(x)(1-x^2)=(1-x^2)y''(x)-4xy'(x)-(1+x^2)y(x)$$

Note that $y(x)(1-x^2)=z(x)$ and the right hand side is equal to $x$. Hence, you get the simple equation.

$$z''(x)+z(x)=x$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: This simplifies. Great.

Comment: Elegant approach !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Sorry, i didn't want to copy you i just wanted to show that your suggestion really leads to an easier expression, without differentiating $z(x)/(1-x^2)$. If you feel like i copied your work, i can delete my answer.

Comment: I really meant that your solution is very elegant and this is the truth ! I never thought that you copied me on any manner.  You please do not delete your answer. Moverover, I upvoted your answer as soon as it came. Again, good answer, my friend !